# windows memory management issues

Tags: windows, memory-management

hey guys so recently installed copy of stripped down windows 10 enterprise LTSC 2019. Im no windows expert so I dont know how or what windows uses to keep hungry software from using as much memory as they want to avoid crashing. Like games they cant get past menu screen without crashing.

I have 8GB of RAM which should be enough but software crashes when I run out of memory. I used to have a normal person version of windows and things worked fine without reaching memory capacity limit and i never had to use swap or whatever you windows people call it.

Can someone enlighten me on how windows is meant to be able to limit memory useage for software and maybe how to re enable these features I dont mind tweaking around registry as long as it works out in the end.

Comment: Ive also noticed that on idle memory use can be in excess of 5GB which to me doesnt seem normal. But thats just my opinion.

Comment: You `should` use swap. I myself use a laptop with 8GB memory, I never found it to be enough. Like you, I tried to disable swap and I ran into out-of-memory situations A LOT.  I don't even play games.

Comment: You *want* Windows to use all your memory. The memory manager is smart enough to use your memory as a large cache for files you might need later but release the memory when your applications need it. If you can't get by the menu screen without crashing, I would first try procmon from sysinternals. If you can't get anything out of that, I'd try procdump and analyze the crash with WinDbg.

Answer (score 2):

8GB is **bare minimum** these days.

Re-enable swap [pagefile].

With swap when it runs out of memory [actually once it goes over half] it will start to page. With no swap, it will crash instead, as you've discovered.

Comment: A I see thanks for the advice turns out 8GB really isn't enough nowadays. Guess i'll re enable swap and upgrade to 16GB once i can afford it